# why sonarqube 6.0 doesn't allow to select metrics of type "Rating" in quality gate definitions?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Reliability Rating, Security Rating and SQUALE Rating doesn't appear in quality gate definition form. Is this a bug or there's some hidden reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

For the record, SonarQube 6.0 doesn't have a SQALE rating, but a Maintainability Rating

While you can't set a Quality Gate condition directly on the Maintainability rating, you can set a condition on the technical debt ratio (the Maintainability Rating is based directly on the tech. debt ratio).

For the Security and Reliability ratings... "bug" is such an ugly word. Let's just say there's a lot to do. :-)

Comment: Didn't meant to be rude, sorry

Comment: No need to apologize. I was being flip in my answer. :-)

Comment: The l10nes pack needs updating.